# Apply a quality gate to only one of the tools

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, quality-gate, warnings-next-generation

I have a series of jenkins **pipeline** jobs which build bitbucket pull requests.
Those pipelines have a Quality stage, which records issues using **warningsng** for GCC warnings and Coverity defects (via the generic issues tool).

The relevant part of my pipeline is:

```
post {
    always {
        recordIssues(
           blameDisabled: true,
           forensicsDisabled: true,
           tools: [gcc(id: "${env.PRODUCT}-static-gcc",
                       name: "${PRODUCT} GCC warnings",
                       pattern: "rw/build-analysis.log"),
                   issues(id: "${env.PRODUCT}-coverity-defects",
                          name: "${PRODUCT} Coverity Defects",
                          pattern: "rw/warning-ng-defects-*.xml")]
        )
    }
}
```

Since we have fixed normally all of our GCC warnings, but we still have lots of Coverity defects, I wanted to apply a quality gate to the **gcc** tool, to reject pull requests with warnings, but not to the **issues** one, since we accept for now, pull requests still having Coverity defects.

But my understanding, from the reading of the pipeline syntax steps reference, is that a quality gate applies to the whole list of tools in **recordIssues**, and doesn't seem to be applicable to only one of the tools.

Here's what I had tried:

```
post {
    always {
        recordIssues(
           blameDisabled: true,
           forensicsDisabled: true,
           tools: [gcc(id: "${env.PRODUCT}-static-gcc",
                       name: "${PRODUCT} GCC warnings",
                       pattern: "rw/build-analysis.log",
                       qualityGates: [[threshold: 1, type: 'TOTAL', unstable: true]]),
                   issues(id: "${env.PRODUCT}-coverity-defects",
                          name: "${PRODUCT} Coverity Defects",
                          pattern: "rw/warning-ng-defects-*.xml")]
        )
    }
}
```

But according to the documentation, it seems logical that it was just plainly ignored.

So, is there a way to apply a quality gate to only one of a tool in a tools list, in recordIssues?

Comment: Why not invoke two `recordIssues`: one for the gcc warnings, and the second for the coverity defects? Then you could only pass the `qualityGates` argument to only one of the two. Are you restricted from that usage in your environment?

Comment: Is it possible? I thought that only one was possible.
I'll try that right now and I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, the solution was simple and "only" consisted in using `recordIssues` twice. This worked for me:

```
post {
    always {
        recordIssues(
           blameDisabled: true,
           forensicsDisabled: true,
           tool: issues(id: "${env.PRODUCT}-coverity-defects",
                        name: "${PRODUCT} Coverity Defects",
                        pattern: "rw/warning-ng-defects-*.xml")
        )
        recordIssues(
           blameDisabled: true,
           forensicsDisabled: true,
           qualityGates: [[threshold: 1, type: 'TOTAL', unstable: false]],
           tool: gcc(id: "${env.PRODUCT}-static-gcc",
                     name: "${PRODUCT} GCC warnings",
                     pattern: "rw/build-analysis.log")
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you very much @MattSchuchard!